# Program stops after assigning values to struct using scanf

Tags: c, struct, scanf

In the following code, the program stops without any errors when I assign it's members values using scanf.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
        int hours, minutes, seconds;
} Time;

int main (void) {
    Time getTime (void);
    Time time;

    time = getTime();

    printf ("%i:%i:%i", time.hours, time.minutes, time.seconds);
}

Time getTime (void) {
    Time time;

    printf ("Enter time (hh:mm:ss): ");
    scanf ("%i:%i:%i", time.hours, time.minutes, time.seconds);

    return time;
}
```

A sample of the output:
`Enter time (hh:mm:ss): 12:12:12` - then the program stops executing

When I add `\n` to the last printf to flush the buffer, it still doesn't change anything.
I've tried to initialize both structures with default values but it made no difference i.e. `Time time = {0, 0, 0};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scanf`'s arguments are of pointer type. Place `&` before with each parameter of `scanf`

```
scanf ("%i:%i:%i", &time.hours, &time.minutes, &time.seconds);
```

Comment: prototype is defined in `main`

Comment: @AlterMann; Missed that :)

Comment: @AlterMann It is perfectly valid to locally declare a function prototype in other function.

Comment: @user2849447; He is not saying it is wrong. He just informed me about that.

Comment: @user2849447, I know, thats what I say ;)

Comment: Is there a reason why it didn't alert me to this error like it usually does with a segmentation error?

Comment: @user2849447; This is an evil thing with `scanf`.

Comment: @AlterMann Will do! :)